# Azure Function blob input binding with a servicebus trigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, serverless

I'm trying to create an Azure Function that triggers on an AZ ServiceBus Queue message. The message contains a GUID string, matching the name of a BLOB on AZ storage. I'd like to have that BLOB available through an input binding but I'm not sure how...

I tried :

```
public static async Task Run(
   [ServiceBusTrigger("outgoing-mail", Connection = "QueueConnString")] string inputMessage,
   [Blob("email-messages/{inputMessage}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream mailBlob,
   [SendGrid(ApiKey = "%SendgridApiKey%")] IAsyncCollector<SendGridMessage> messageCollector,
   ILogger log)
```

I also tried {serviceBusTrigger} on the blob path by-the-way but either way, I get the following exception :

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'SendMailQueueWorker'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Unable to resolve
>   binding parameter 'inputMessage'. Binding expressions must map to
>   either a value provided by the trigger or property of the value the
>   trigger is bound to or must be a system binding expression (e.g.
>   sys.randguid, sys.utcnow, etc.).

I'm sure the input message of the queue is a string, how can I use this message content in the input binding of the BLOB?

[edit]
I added the feature request to UserVoice, so if you're running into this issue as well, please vote!
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/37528912-combine-servicebus-queue-message-with-storage-inpu
[/edit]

Answer (score 6):

Looks like this isn't supported for Service Bus Trigger the way it is for Queue Trigger.
You could raise a feature request on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions) for this.

**But** one thing to note is that this limitation holds *only* for non-JSON messages. If you send a JSON message instead, it will get parsed as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#json-payloads).

Your function could be something like this

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace funk_csharp_queue
{
  public class QueueMsg
  {
    public string filename { get; set; }
  }
  public static class ServiceBusTrigger
  {
    [FunctionName("ServiceBusTrigger")]
    public static void Run(
      [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] QueueMsg myQueueItem,
      [Blob("samples-workitems/{filename}", FileAccess.Read)] String myBlob,
      ILogger log)
    {
      log.LogInformation($"C# Service Bus trigger function processed: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myQueueItem)}");
      log.LogInformation($"C# Blob input read: {myBlob}");
    }
  }
}
```

And the message you send in the Service Bus Queue / Topic would be something like this

```
{
  "filename": "11c8f49d-cddf-4b82-a980-e16e8a8e42f8.json"
}
```

Make sure you set the [Content Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messages-payloads#payload-serialization) to `application/json`.

Comment: Pretty clear answer there, I'll definitely post it to UserVoice as it seems to be a pretty straight forward and clean solution. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's directly possible as you would like to. I would just use a `CloudBlobContainer` [input binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input---usage) to work around this.

```
[Blob("email-messages", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "BlobConnectionString")] CloudBlobContainer blobContainer
```

Then use the blobContainer to read the blob in your function using the inputMessage.

```
CloudBlob mailBlob = blobContainer.GetBlobReference(inputMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I thought the service bus queue was the way to go, but I used a storage queue instead. It works like a charm with the storage queue trigger. When removing all bindings, the service bus trigger didn't even fire when messages arrived. It think the trigger itself has a couple of bugs... storage queue ftw